# How to strip and convert this using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on allowing users to make mentions and it's saved in the database this way `@[Abdullah](61dfaceadef99a95503119a8)` sometimes can be in a sentence or paragraph.

How can i make so that if a sentence or paragraph contains a mention it's converted?

From: `hey @[Abdullah](61dfaceadef99a95503119a8) check this out and @[James](61dfaceadef99a95514562) welcome to the group!`

To: `hey Abdullah check this out and James welcome to the group!`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had time to get it done and came up with an answer also thanks to @Denton Thomas answer i was able to understand what to do.

```
let str = "hey @[Abdullah](61dfaceadef99a95503119a8) check this out and @[James](61dfaceadef99a95514562) welcome to the group!";

let regexp = /((.)\[([^[]*)]\(([^(^)]*)\))/gi 
var result = str.replace(regexp, function(data){
  console.log("data:", data)
  let name = data.match(/([^[]+(?=]))/g)
  console.log("name:", name)
  return name[0]
});

console.log("message:", result );
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the language/platform, your RE pattern will have three parts:

- mark the start of the string as a capture group: @[
- match the middle of the string: Abdullah
- mark the rest of the string as a capture group: ](61dfaceadef99a95503119a8)

Assuming you're just looking for the regex pattern in ECMAScript, you'll need something like:

`(\@\[).*(\]\([a-f0-9]+\))`

Run that through match() or matchAll() to identify matches, or use replace() on the matches. [javascript.info has an example using capture groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#capturing-groups-in-replacement) - that looks close enough to your scenario.